# How to segue an object to a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I'm trying to segue an object from a table cell to a `UITabBarController`. My code to send the segue to a view controller is this:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateContacts"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView    indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.contactdb = selectedDevice;
        refreshControl = nil;
    }
}
```

Also in DetailsViewController.h I´m adding the `contactdb` property
this one is working ok, now i don't know how to segue it to a `UITabBarController` so i can access it from my 2 view controllers that i have in the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Remember to avoid thank taglines in the questions, you can read why in here: "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear, is DetailViewController your TabBarController you are referring to?

Generally speaking, when you want to pass data between view controllers where the flow is a little more complex than normal, you can use a notification/listener pattern. For example, in the passing controller you would do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_REFRESH 
                                                    object:contactDb];
```

In your receiving controller, you would register to listen to the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(gotData:) 
                                             name:NOTIFICATION_REFRESH 
                                           object:nil];
```

And in that same controller, here is the code to capture that notification and object:

```
- (void)gotData:(NSNotification *) notification {
   NSObject *myData = [notification object];
}
```

You will need to define the notification types in a header like this:

```
extern NSString* const NOTIFICATION_REFRESH;
```

And it's implementation in the .m file like this:

```
NSString* const NOTIFICATION_REFRESH = @"notificationRefresh";
```

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of purpose I usually keep a singleton object that is visible in any place of project (makin #import in .pch file). Then I declare all necessary propeties which I want to share between different objects (e.g. controllers) and use them by assigning values and accesing. For instance, in prepareForSegue I would assign contactdb property declared in that common singleton object and then get the value from other controller.

Comment: so theres no way to directly pass it with segue in my tabbarcontroller and then make it accessible to my viewcontrollers in there?